# How to have a listview in air application with good performance

Tags: performance, listview, air, components

I'm working on an android air application in which i need to have a list of too many items (for example 500 items at the same time. is there any component which can help me with this?

I want items to be removed when they are out of the screen and when they're coming to screen to be attached to the list so the performance and memory usage will be as much good as possible.

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be as follows:

- Implement your custom ListViewAdapter by extending the BaseAdapter
  class.
- Have a look at the ViewHolder pattern, it's basically the main
  part of your requirement. You will use it in the getView() callback of the adapter.

  [ViewHolder pattern example](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html)
- As a datasource for your custom adapter you could use the generic
  SparseArray, it is very fast in retrieving items by their index. You
  could pass a SparseArray filled with your data into the adapter,
  while scrolling - the getView callback will provide an index that
  you'll use to display your data.